# not working command when user is mentioned

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a piece of code that returns a Rich Embed with the Avatar of the mentioned user or the message author if it hasn't got a mention, the code works without mentioning but it doesn't work when mentioning someone. (No error in the console)

```js
if (message.content === prefix + "avatar") {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
        const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
            .setColor("#13e2c0")
            .setTitle("Avatar")
            .setImage(message.author.avatarURL())
        message.channel.send(Embed)
    }
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(user.tag, user.avatarURL())
        .setColor("#13e2c0")
        .setTitle("Avatar")
        .setImage(user.avatarURL())
    message.channel.send(Embed)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no users mentions, `message.mentions.users.size`, will always be 0, not `NULL` or `undefined`.

---

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "avatar")) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(user.tag, user.avatarURL())
        .setColor("#13e2c0").setTitle("Avatar")
        .setImage(user.avatarURL())
    return message.channel.send(Embed);
}
```

Comment: The command still doesn't works when mentioning someone, it continue like before changing it.

Comment: Can I get the script that you are currently using?

Comment: if (message.content === prefix + "avatar") {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(user.tag, user.avatarURL())
      .setColor("#13e2c0")
      .setTitle("Avatar")
      .setImage(user.avatarURL())
    message.channel.send(Embed);
  }

Comment: It is because you are checking if the message equals exactly with "!avatar", where `!` is the prefix. When you mention someone the message will look something like `!avatar <@UserID>`. I've updated my code, please tell me if still you encounter the issue.

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot, i really didn't understand what toLowerCase mean.

Comment: It transforms your message to lowercase, so commands such as `!AvAtAR`, `!AVATAR`, `!aVatAR` are working.